How to implement ADFS authentication and Authorization in .NET Core
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
    {
        sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = WsFederationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddWsFederation(options =>
    {
        options.Wtrealm = "urn:DevTest";
        options.MetadataAddress = "https://example.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml";
        options.Wreply = "https://localhost:44341/Home/Index/";

    })
    .AddCookie();

Is ASP.NET identity mandatory for this implementation if we need to use claims?
 ClaimsIdentity id = ((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity);
 var claim = id.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email);

I am getting false in IsAuthenticated:
I have tried this with another existing ASP.NET MVC application. The ADFS configuration works there.
Can anyone provide a sample implementation for ADFS authentication and claims-based authorization?
Upon investigation, i found that the NameID claim is not set up in AFDS server. That can be a reason for this authentication failure?
The claims Identity IsAuthenticated sets up based on Authentication type. This value is null. Is this due to the missing NameID claim?
ClaimsIdentity.cs:
   public virtual bool IsAuthenticated
   {
       get { return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_authenticationType); }
   }


https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/ws-federation?view=aspnetcore-8.0

@PowerMouse I had referred this documentation only. But authentication not working.
